# How do I access data from a dynamic array in c?

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic

I've got two different arrays that I'm using.  With one, I'm getting the exact results that I want, the other, not so much.  I'm filing the arrays with by reading from a text file similar to this:

```
2597
283



4
723
21
82
426
```

The first five lines would be the customer IDs.  There is always 5 lines but they don't always have a value.  The next line is the number of vendors, then followed by the vendor ids.

```
void use_arrays()
{
    int
        i,
        customer_count,
        *customer_ids,
        vendor_count,
        *vendor_ids;

    customer_ids = malloc(sizeof(int));
    vendor_ids = malloc(sizeof(int));
    fill_arrays(&customer_count, customer_ids, &vendor_count, vendor_ids);

    for (i = 0; i < customer_count; i++)
    {
        printf("Customer[%d]: %d\n", i, customer_ids[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < vendor_count; i++)
    {
        printf("Vendor[%d]: %d\n", i, vendor_ids[i]);
    }

    free(customer_ids);
    free(vendor_ids);
}

void fill_arrays(int *customer_count, int *customer_ids, int *vendor_count, int *vendor_ids)
{
    int
        i,
        *temp,
        customer_id,
        vendor_id,
        num_cust = 0;
    FILE
        *inp_file;
    char
        *endptr = NULL,
        buffer[500];

    inp_file = fopen(g_filename, "r");

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) /* Can't be more than 5 customers */
    {
        fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), inp_file);
        customer_id = strtol(buffer, &endptr, 0);
        if (customer_id != 0)
        {
            customer_ids[i] = customer_id;
        temp = realloc(customer_ids, (i+2)*sizeof(int));
        if (temp != NULL) 
            {
               customer_ids = temp;
            } 
        else 
        {
               printf("Couldn't allocate memory\n");
            }
        num_cust++;
        }
    }
    *customer_count = num_cust;

    /* Next is number of vendor ids*/
    fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), inp_file);
    *vendor_count = strtol(buffer, &endptr, 0);

    temp = realloc(vendor_ids, *vendor_count*sizeof(int));
    if (temp != NULL) 
    {
        vendor_ids = temp;
    } 
    else 
    {
        printf("Couldn't allocate memory\n");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < *vendor_count; i++)
    {
        fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), inp_file);
        vendor_id = strtol(buffer, &endptr, 0);
        if (vendor_id != 0)
        {
        vendor_ids[i] = vendor_id;
        }
    }
    fclose(inp_file);
}
```

Once the arrays print out, `customer_ids` is showing the correct numbers but `vendor_ids` is printing out random numbers from memory.  To be more frustrating, it prints the vendors correctly from inside `fill_arrays`.

Comment: a good tip is to always check return codes, normally when you assume something it is often wrong.

Comment: reallocating is a costly operation, when you reallocate, allocate a chunk instead. if u know that you are reading 5 numbers allocate 5 numbers at start

Comment: I'm reallocating because I don't know how many numbers there will be.  There could be 5, but it might just be one also.

Comment: yes but when you reallocate you could say allocate 10 objects at one time instead of just one. then if u use up those 10, allocate another 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to modify `vendor_ids` the way you do in `fill_arrays`, then you have to pass it in as a pointer to a pointer:

```
fill_arrays(int *customer_count, int *customer_ids, int *vendor_count, int **vendor_ids)
```

Call it like this:

```
fill_arrays(&customer_count, customer_ids, &vendor_count, &vendor_ids);
```

Then you can realloc like so:

```
temp = realloc(*vendor_ids, *vendor_count*sizeof(int));
if (temp != NULL) 
{
    *vendor_ids = temp;
}
```

Also, at the end of your function:

```
vendor_ids[i] = vendor_id;
```

will have to change to

```
(*vendor_ids)[i] = vendor_id;
```

You will also have to make the same changes to `customer_ids`.  The fact that `customer_ids` was working while `vendor_ids` wasn't was probably due to your use of `realloc`.  If `realloc` decides that the memory block has to be reallocated in a new location, you'll run into these problems but if reallocates the memory in the same location, your pointer that you passed in is still pointing there.  Since you never know if `realloc` is going to make that descision or not, both `customer_ids` and `vendor_ids` should be passed in as pointers to pointers.

Comment: `customer_ids` will require the same.

Comment: @netcoder +1 Added a blurb at the end about that.  Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Nice, thanks.  I got it working with this.  When I added it to customer_ids however, I got access violations.  I'm guessing I might have done something else wrong.  But I'm curious, what is the danger of leaving it as is if I am getting the correct answer?

Comment: @vikingsfan19 Happy to help. Can I see the code at the line where you're getting an access violtation?  Also, the danger of leaving the code as it was is that when you `realloc` and the location of the allocated memory decides it needs to change, you now have a lingering pointer that's pointing to trash data and once the function ends, if you didn't use a pointer to a pointer, that allocated memory at the new location will just be floating around, un-handled. (AKA a memory leak)

Comment: Ah, actually I figured it out.  I just missed a spot.

Answer (score 0):

You seem a bit confused how to return memory from a function.

if you have a function that looks like this

`void foo(int a);`

you can not change `a` inside of foo, foo only gets a copy of a.

`void foo(int *a);`

otoh gives foo the address of a, i.e. "i know where you live" it lets you change what `a` points to. if `a` points to an array then you can change the contents of that array, if a points to a single integer you can change that.

`void foo(int **a);`

lets you change not only what `a` points to, but also where it points. so if you want `a` to point to somewhere else you can. this is what you need in your function, if you do a malloc/calloc/realloc in your function to return the result you need this

Comment: So the way I was trying to do it essentially was like sending a copy of the array?  Is that why the extra * is necessary?

Comment: `fill_arrays(int *customer_count,..` would never allow you to change the size of `customer_count` because realloc creates a new block in memory